# How do I parametrize Lua script to go through table values executing queries

Tags: database, lua, lua-table, exasol

new with Lua but trying.

I have multiple "Create table" queries which I need to execute, what changes only is Schema and Table name.
At the moment I am explicitly defining each query.
I want to parametrize Lua script from the table below passing table name as argument, since there is 100+ tables which needs to be generated this way.

MappingTable

| targetSchema | targetTable | originSchema | originTable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| schema1 | table1 | schema3 | table3 |
| schema2 | table2 | schema4 | table4 |

Current solution

```
CREATE LUA SCRIPT "ScriptName" () RETURNS ROWCOUNT AS
query([[
Create or replace table schema1.table1 as
select * from schema3.table3;
]])
query([[
Create or replace table schema2.table2 as
select * from schema4.table4;
]])
```

What I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LUA SCRIPT "ScriptName"('MappingTable') RETURNS ROWCOUNT AS
map_table = execute[[ SELECT * FROM .."'MappingTableName'"..;]] -- passing argument of the script, mapping table name

-- passing values from the columns

load =   [[Create or replace table ]]..
                  [[']]..targetSchema..[['.']].. 
                  [[']]..targetTable..]]..
                  [[as select * from]]..
                  [[']]..originSchema..[['.']]..
                  [[']]..originTable..[[']]
```

Not sure about the syntax, also I guess I need to loop through the values of the table.
Thank you

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: RDBMS is Exasol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample script:

```
create or replace lua script ScriptName (
      t_MappingTable
    , s_ConditionColumn
    , s_ConditionValue
)
returns rowcount as

-- passing argument of the script, mapping table name
local map_table = query ([[
select * from ::MappingTable where ::ConditionColumn = :ConditionValue
]],{
      MappingTable = t_MappingTable
    , ConditionColumn = s_ConditionColumn
    , ConditionValue = s_ConditionValue
});

-- passing values from the columns
for i = 1, #map_table do
    query ([[
    create or replace table ::targetSchema.::targetTable as
    select * from ::originSchema.::originTable
    ]],{
          targetSchema = map_table[i].TARGETSCHEMA
        , targetTable  = map_table[i].TARGETTABLE
        , originSchema = map_table[i].ORIGINSCHEMA
        , originTable  = map_table[i].ORIGINTABLE
    });
end
/
```

You may want to read values from `map_table` the other way.

In case when you have case-sensitive column names:

```
  targetSchema = map_table[i]."targetSchema"
, targetTable  = map_table[i]."targetTable"
, originSchema = map_table[i]."originSchema"
, originTable  = map_table[i]."originTable"
```

In case when you are sure in column order and don't want to worry about column names:

```
  targetSchema = map_table[i][1]
, targetTable  = map_table[i][2]
, originSchema = map_table[i][3]
, originTable  = map_table[i][4]
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you @GriGrim. 
What if I want to pass the field to the condition
```
where ::ConditionField ='::conditionColumn'
```
This is not working. What would be correct syntax for the value in the condition?

Comment: Ah ok. If I want to add it in the conditionValue then it is a single :

Comment: Yes. When you use variable for an object/column, then use double colon `::`.
When you pass a string, then use single colon `:`.